# Asterisk 13.21.cert3 error loading res_rtp_asterisk.so module

Tags: centos7, asterisk

We are upgrading (or trying) our asterisk servers from version 13.13.cert9 to version 13.21.cert3 and we are facing some issues.

This are the steps followed to build it :

1. Download and untar the source code
2. From the uncompressed folder execute the command below to configure the application

`./configure --libdir=/usr/lib64 --prefix=/home/asterisk --with-pjproject-bundled`

3. Execute `make menuselect`, then choose the following options :

   - Call Detail Recording ==> cdr_csv
   - Channel Drivers ==> chan_sip
   - Format Interpreters ==> format_vox
   - Resource Modules ==> res_snmp, res_timing_pthread
4. Build install and asterisk

   ```
   make -j3
   make install
   make config
   make samples
   make install-logrotate
   ```

When I start the service there are no errors in log files

By default res_rtp_asterisk.so is not loaded eventhough is configured in `modules.cfg` file. Verified with `rasterisk` => `module show`

When trying to load manually the module, console outputs this message:

```
WARNING[25352]: loader.c:583 load_dlopen: Error loading module 'res_rtp_asterisk.so': /usr/lib64/asterisk/modules/res_rtp_asterisk.so: undefined symbol: ast_pjproject_caching_pool_destroy
WARNING[25352]: loader.c:1182 load_resource: Module 'res_rtp_asterisk.so' could not be loaded.
```

When trying to make a phone call to test the service I have the message below on logs

```
WARNING[25322]: loader.c:583 in load_dlopen: Error loading module 'res_rtp_asterisk.so': /usr/lib64/asterisk/modules/res_rtp_asterisk.so: undefined symbol: ast_pjproject_caching_pool_destroy
```

Nothing change in the way we compile asterisk from version 13.13.c9 to version 13.21.c3

**Any clue of what I'm missing ?**

Comment: The module you're trying to load probably needs another module loaded first. In this case it seems to be `res_pjproject.so`.

Comment: Thank you @MartinSugioarto !! It's a same that I've found the answer this morning without seeing your answer, actually there is a major bug on asteriks 13.X as indicated in this [thread](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-26518)

Answer (score 1):

So, finally, there was a **bug** as described in this [thread](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-26518)

Applying the patch in [this repo](http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/certified-asterisk/) the problem dissapear

[Here](http://usecallmanager.nz/patching-asterisk.html) are the instructions to apply the patch

**I hope it can help anyone in the same situation**

Quiet disturbing for a certified version